# Wifi card not found

Tags: networking

Computer is an Asus T200TA
Output from sudo lshw -C network:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enx7824afca429d
       serial: 78:24:af:ca:42:9d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.08.3 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.157 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

I have 2 of these machines. One is loaded with Ubuntu 16.04 the other is still running Windows 10 and its Wifi works fine. I get the same answer on the machine running Windows 10 when I boot from an Ubuntu disk. When I run lshw - there is no wifi card showing

Edit from comments: `lspci -v` output is as follows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0d) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0d) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xx
Series Graphics & Display Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 206 Memory at 90000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M] Memory at 80000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] I/O ports at 1000 [size=8] [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K] Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: i915 Kernel modules: i915 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0d) (prog-if 30 [XHCI]) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx
Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 204 Memory at 90800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd Kernel modules: xhci_pci 00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0d) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx
Series Trusted Execution Engine Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 215 Memory at 90700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M] Memory at 90600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M] Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: mei_txe Kernel modules: mei_txe 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0d) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx
Series Power Control Unit Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0 Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich Kernel modules: lpc_ich
```

Comment: What is the result of the terminal command: dmesg | grep brcm Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: please also post the output of `lspci -v`

Comment: Hi again, there is no output in response to dmesg | grep brcm. For lspci -v I get:

Comment: 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0d)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
 Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0d) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx ' then

Comment: Series Graphics & Display
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 206
 Memory at 90000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
 Memory at 80000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 I/O ports at 1000 [size=8]
 [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0d) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx,

Comment: Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 204
 Memory at 90800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
 Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0d)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx

Comment: Series Trusted Execution Engine
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 215
 Memory at 90700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
 Memory at 90600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
 Kernel modules: mei_txe

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0d)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx

Comment: Series Power Control Unit
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
 Kernel modules: lpc_ich

Comment: How about: `dmesg | grep -i sdio`

Comment: This also gives zero output

Comment: How about: `dmesg | grep -i bcm` or: `dmesg | grep firm` I am running low on ideas! Also, on the Windows machine, are there any clues as to the exact identity of the wireless device?

Comment: @chil555 according to [this](https://www.asus.com/us/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T200TA/HelpDesk_Download/) it should have a broadcom chip of some variety. Sorry, I've got nothing else

Comment: Hi, No output for either of those. As far as I am aware it does have a Broadcom chip but it does seem determined on these two machines to stay hidden. Thanks for trying but I think I'll probably have to try getting a dongle

Comment: I went back to the Windows machine and determined that the Wifi is broadcom 802.11abgn wireless sdio adapter. I Googled and came up with this link https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=206781.  I followed the instruction sudo cp /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-43268123d113 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt to rename the file then ran dmesg | grep -l sdio again and came up with:

Comment: [    7.958711] r8152 1-4.3:1.0 eth0: v1.08.3
[    8.008467] brcmf_sdio_drivestrengthinit: No SDIO Drive strength init done for chip 43340 rev 2 pmurev 20
[    8.009066] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    8.056948] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt failed with error -2
[    8.219608] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
--
[   12.263689] fuse init (API version 7.24)
[   13.025152] brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   14.032019] brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50

Comment: I took out the references to the audio ports. Does this mean I've now located the Broadcom device? Don't know what to do now though...

Comment: And this when I run dmesg | grep -1 bcm: [    7.181353] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    7.196883] hci_bcm BCM2E65:00: BCM irq: 192
[    7.196918] hci_bcm BCM2E65:00: BCM2E65:00 device registered.
[    7.197095] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered

Comment: But still nothing more when I run lshw -C network

Answer (score 0):

In your comments, you say that you did:

```
sudo cp /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-4326‌​8123d113 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt
```

However, in your `dmesg` result, it says:

> Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt failed with error
>   -2

As you can see, you followed a post from another thread that involves a slightly different device, a Broadcom 43241b4, evidently. Your `dmesg` says it wants a firmware file for a Broadcom 43340.

First, are you certain that this sequence is accurate for your machine?

> /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/**nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-4326‌​8123d113**

Please check:

```
ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/  | grep nvram
```

If it is correct, please do:

```
sudo cp /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-4326‌​8123d113 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
```

Reboot.

If the bolded sequence is above is *not* correct for your machine, post the result and we'll proceed.

Your wireless device will not appear in `lshw` now or ever as `lshw` doesn't (yet?) see SDIO devices. You may stop checking.

EDIT: If you are having trouble with the command, let's try another approach.

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm && ls
```

Based on your previous attempt, you should have a file called brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt. If so, let's copy it:

```
sudo cp brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt  brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thanks. The number seemed to be correct after entering ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/  | grep nvram but when I entered sudo cp /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-4326‌​8123d113 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt, I get cp: cannot stat '/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-4326‌​8123d113': Invalid argument

Comment: Please recheck your steps. If the sequence is correct as I bolded above, and as you verified, then the file can't be missing. Please note that there is a space, not a line break, between the sequence and /lib/firmware/etc. It is one long command. You might have better luck if you copy and paste the whole thing.

Comment: Let's try another approach. Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.